# wpf: trouble binding to subclass

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, textbox

I have problems understanding the binding to a property in a subclass.
This is my code:
MainWindow.XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Datagrid_vs_Database.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Datagrid_vs_Database"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtPath" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentDatabase.FullFilePath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding openFileBrowser}" Content="New Database"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Manager.cs

```
public class Manager
{
    private static readonly Manager instance = new Manager();
    public static Manager Instance { get { return instance; } }
    public IComOpenFileBrowser openFileBrowser { get; private set; }
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    public Database CurrentDatabase;

    private Manager()
    {
        openFileBrowser = new IComOpenFileBrowser(SaveFileDialog);
        CurrentDatabase = new Database();

        mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.DataContext = this;
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void SaveFileDialog()
    {
        var sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Title = "Choose a filename and a directory to store the new database";
        sfd.Filter = "SQLite Database (*.sqlite)|*.sqlite";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            CurrentDatabase.FullFilePath = sfd.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

database.cs

```
public class Database : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _FullFilePath;
    public string FullFilePath {
        get {
            return _FullFilePath;
        }
        set { _FullFilePath = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The thing is when I click on the Button, the SaveFileDialog appears, but when I type in a name and click OK, the Filename does not appear in the Textbox.

BUT: When I set mainWindow.txtPath.DataContext = CurrentDatabase; and delete the "CurrentDatabase." from the XAML code then it works.
I thought that it's correct to set the DataContext of the whole window to the manager class and then access the subclass in XAML by ..{Binding Path= CurrentDatabase.FullFilePath}..
But obviously thats not the case. 
Can anybody tell my what I'm misunderstanding here?

Comment: First of all please understand what is a subclass, you can't use the terms as you like and secondly I don't understand your "Manager" class. Assuming you know what you are doing in Manager class, there should be no problem in binding textbox text like the way you are doing. Try making the "CurrentDatabase" a CLR property, it should work then.

Comment: Thank you. Got it! Both with the CLR Property as well as with the subclass naming. I'm working on that :-)